# laravel tenancy subdomain makes Auth in central database

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I'm using `stancl/tenancy` library.

I have a central domain (example.com) and a tenant subdomain (tenant.example.com).

The problem is that the login in the tenant subdomain is trying to auth through central database. I have:

```
dd(tenant()); // this shows the right tenant
Auth::attempt($credentials_array); // this tries to auth in central database
```

I've been a couple of days checking configuration and everything seems to work fine. Any idea of what could I be missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! As almost always happens, the biggest problems comes from the dumbest places.

At some point someone updated the env variable REDIS_CLIENT from `phpredis` to `predis`.

I had to set `REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis` in the `.env`.

refresh cache "et voilà!".

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

i know it different case than mine , but I'm just puting this here for other people as I spent almost a day for it , because I used the tall presets , and there was livewire , make sure you add livewire specific changes https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/integrations/livewire
and don't forget to add